# How to send data to localMember Instance always

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Is there any way that I can allot the keys to the partitions owned by LocalMember Instance.
We are running embedded mode Hazelcast.
Data Locality and nearness is needed at each node.One way could be to ensure that PartitionAwareStrategy could help point to localMember partitions and the keys could be assigned to local Member partitions.Below is some code to exemplify.

```
      PartitionService  ps=  instance.getPartitionService();
      Member m = instance.getCluster().getLocalMember();
      List<Integer> pls = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for(Partition p : ps.getPartitions()) {
          Member pm = p.getOwner();
        //Local Member Partitions
          if(m.getUuid().equals(pm.getUuid())) {
              pls.add(p.getPartitionId());
          }
      }
    //Need Logic Here.Keys need to be Partition Aware but how do we inject Local Member partitions 
    allotKeys(pls);
```

Answer (score 0):

Partitions are managed by Hazelcast, and moved from member to member as the cluster changes.

Even if you placed data in a partition that was currently on the local member, it can be moved elsewhere.

If you need locality, have a low update rate and can tolerate eventual consistency, why not check out [Near Cache](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.4/manual/html-single/index.html#creating-near-cache-for-map) -- a local subset copy of data that is elsewhere.